# Hola buenas tardes, tengo un pequeño error de un programa que trata crear una tabla de amortización y imprimirla por consola, java

Tags: java

Estoy usando arreglo pero al momento de cambiar el atributo de la siguiente posición no me lo cambia, cual seria el problema.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado me sale:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual necesito que la cuota del elemento [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4z54.png)  sea igual al saldo del elemento[0] hay se realizan los cálculos respectivos del elemento[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4z54.png) y así sucesivamente hasta llegar al ultimo elemento. Estaría agradecido por la ayuda, soy nuevo en Java

Comment: Hola y bienvenido, procura adjuntar tu código como texto y no como imagen es mas fácil y ayuda a entender un poco mas tu problema, a simple vista estas creando un mismo objeto en cada iteración, una vez creado debes guardarlo ya sea en un array o arralist para que no accedas solo al ultimo objeto creado

Comment: me gustaría ayudarte, pero no entiendo muy bien de la manera que lo expresas me resulta imposible entender, si lo pusieras mas legible te ayudo sin problemas, no parece difícil.

Comment: Quiero que es valor de Saldo que esta pintado de rojo se me asigne a la cuota de la siguiente interacción

Comment: ok, crea una variable fuera del for que se llame el valor que quieres guardar, y en la siguiente interaccion lo aplicas en el campo del objeto que quieras
y ya con eso estaria todo ok.